# Cargar imagen desde MySQL a ImageView JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

Necesito cargar una imagen que esta almacenada en MySQL
Esta tabla llamada conductores contiene estas columnas:

[image: Ruta e Imagen]

Logré guardarlas pero ahora necesito obtenerlas cuando el usuario busque ese conductor por su número de identidad personal.

He obtenido los demás datos pero no sé como obtener la foto aquí les muestro el código.

```
public void ConsultarConductor(String cedulaC, Connection claseJava) {

    try {

        PreparedStatement stmt = claseJava.prepareStatement("SELECT nombre, cedula, fechanac, lugarnac, nacionalidad, tiposangre, padecimiento, numerolicencia, tipolicen, licenciaexpedida, licenciaexpira, numempleado, ruta, imagen FROM conductores WHERE cedula = ? ");
        stmt.setString(1, cedulaC);

        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (result.next()) {
            NombreC.setText(result.getString(1));
            CedC.setText(result.getString(2));
            FechaNac.setValue(result.getDate(3).toLocalDate());
            LugarNac.setText(result.getString(4));
            Nacionalidad.setText(result.getString(5));
            TipoSangre.setValue(result.getString(6));
            Padecimiento.setText(result.getString(7));
            NumLic.setText(result.getString(8));
            TipoLic.setValue(result.getString(9));
            LicExpedida.setValue(result.getDate(10).toLocalDate());
            LicExpira.setValue(result.getDate(11).toLocalDate());
            NumEmpleado.setText(result.getString(12));
            txt_rutafoto.setText(result.getString(13));
            img_verfoto.setText(result.getString(14));
        }
        Actualizar.setDisable(false);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es obtener el objeto **Blob** de la columna imagen, luego conviertes el mismo a un arreglo de **bytes[]**, este último lo usas para crear el **Image** que se mostrará en el **ImageView** de JavaFX.

```
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();

while (result.next()) {
    //...

    byte byteImage[] = null;

    // obtener la columna imagen, luego el arreglo de bytes 
    Blob blob = result.getBlob("imagen");
    byteImage = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());

    // crear el Image y mostrarlo en el ImageView
    Image img = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteImage));
    imageView = new ImageView(img);
}
```

Recuerda declarar y agregar el ImageView al Scene de tu aplicación.